# How to make database containing Image and some description?

Tags: android, sql

I am making one button.Clicking on that will open one by one pages.Each page will contain an Image and some description. So one by one page will come. But I dont want to make layout for every individual page.So instead of that I want to make database containing Image and description and I will call from that. I am new to SQlite.So will you help me to figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to make a layout for every page. You can one make one layout with a button, imageview, and a textview for the description. When the user press the button you would query the next row on the database. For more information on how to setup the SQlite see this tutorial [Notepad Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html).